# MySQL parameter resource error

Tags: php, mysql, parameters

Here is my error:

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given...

This refers to line 23 of my code which is:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection)
```

My entire query code looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from users WHERE userid='".intval( $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] )."'"; 
                $result = mysql_query($query, $connection)
                or die ("Couldn't perform query $query <br />".mysql_error());

                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I don't have a clue what has happpened here. All I wanted to do was to have the value of the users 'fullname' displayed in the header section of my web page. So I am outputting this code immediately after to try and achieve this:

```
echo 'Hello '; echo $row['fullname'];
```

Before this change, I had it working perfectly, where the session variable of fullname was echoed $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']. However, because my user can update their information (including their name), I wanted the name displayed in the header to be updated accordingly, and not displaying the session value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$connection` variable is `NULL` that's what your error message is referring to.

Reason being is that you have not called [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Once called it will assign you a *resource* where you can set it to the `$connection` variable, thus being non-null.

As an example:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
// now $connection has a resource that you can pass to mysql_query
$query = "SELECT * from users WHERE userid='".
                                         intval( $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] )."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I needed the connection because before I was simply using the session to retrieve the data... but now with the information coming from the database, i simply did a <?php require_once('config.php');

Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem, anytime, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

include the mysql connections on your class file, for example:

connections/mysql.php

```
<?
$hostname_MySQL = "localhost";
$database_MySQL = "database";
$username_MySQL = "user";
$password_MySQL = "password";

$MySQL = mysql_pconnect($hostname_MySQL, $username_MySQL, $password_MySQL) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_MySQL,$MySQL);
?>
```

class.php

```
<?
include "Connections/MySQL.php";
class utils {
    public function myFunction()
        {
        global $MySQL;
        $sql =  "select * from table"; 
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $MySQL) or die(mysql_error());
        $filas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
        $totalFilas = mysql_num_rows($rs);
        ...
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this, you need to use `mysql_connect` to connect to your database, you can pass this to `mysql_query` if you desire, if you don't pass anything to `mysql_query` PHP uses the last link opened from `mysql_connect`

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus 
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Have you connected to your database? If so please show this code too.

For now, just try removing the `$connection` variable, like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

$connection is assigned the value of the database connection resource id. You don't have that in your script, so the value of $connection is NULL, and that is why you are getting the error. You need to connect to the database before using mysql_query(). You should be okay after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
$connection=mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
if($connection === false) {
 echo "Error in connection mysql_error()";
}
```